# Convert sequence in MS doc to fasta or genbank

Tags: fasta, format-conversion, genbank, egf

How can I convert a sequence provided in a Microsoft doc file into a fasta or genbank format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CrazyDoc](https://github.com/Edinburgh-Genome-Foundry/crazydoc) Python package can convert Genbank/Fasta/Snapgene/MSDoc sequences into Biopython records, which can be saved as Genbank or Fasta.

A web interface / demo is provided at EGF CUBA (Collection
of Useful Biological Apps): [Convert Sequence Files](https://cuba.genomefoundry.org/convert_sequence_files).

*Disclaimer: I'm the current maintainer of CrazyDoc.*

Answer (score 0):

A fasta file is just in plain text format. [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/index.html) can convert `.docx` format to plain text format:

```
pandoc -i input.docx -t plain >output.fasta
```